# Array to string conversion in Route

Tags: arrays, laravel, routes

I'm imploding the Socialite driver from `config\auth` but getting the error called `Array to string conversion`

This is the route:

```
Route::get('redirect/{driver}', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToProvider')
      ->name('login.provider')
      ->where('driver', implode('|', config('auth.socialite.drivers')));
```

These are the drivers on `config.auth.socialite`

````
    'socialite' => [
        'drivers' => [

            'github' => [
                'client_id' => env('GITHUB_KEY'),
                'client_secret' => env('GITHUB_SECRET'),
                'redirect' => env('GITHUB_REDIRECT_URI')
            ],

            'google' => [
                'client_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_ID'),
                'client_secret' => env('GOOGLE_CLIENT_SECRET'),
                'redirect' => env('GOOGLE_CALLBACK_URL'),
            ],
        ],
    ],```
````

Comment: Print out the implode('|', config('auth.socialite.drivers')) value and show the results

Comment: getting same error ```array to string conversion```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only want the keys listed under drivers, so try something like:

```
Route::get('redirect/{driver}', 'Auth\LoginController@redirectToProvider')
      ->name('login.provider')
      ->where('driver', implode('|', array_keys(config('auth.socialite.drivers'))));
```